# Breaking a big insert query into smaller ones

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below `INSERT` query.  It tries to insert over 50,000 rows and it fails because of logging.  Is there a good way of splitting a query like this into batches of about 1000 or so with `COMMIT` statements so that it is not just one big statement?

```
INSERT INTO xxx (....) SELECT .... FROM xx
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DECLARE @rc INT = 1;
WHILE @rc > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  INSERT dbo.target(cols) 
    SELECT TOP (5000) cols 
    FROM dbo.source AS s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.target AS t
      WHERE t.key = s.key
    )
    ORDER BY clustering_key;

  SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Also see:

- [Break large delete operations into chunks](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes)